Model showing zero accuracy and almost zero loss when evaluated on the testing dataset?
I have a deep learning model that seems to perform exceptionally well during training, achieving nearly 70% accuracy with almost zero loss. However, when I evaluate the same model on my testing dataset, it exhibits nearly zero loss but zero accuracy. Here is my code
Before defining the create_global_model() method, I aimed to establish a neural network architecture suitable for image classification tasks. The architecture consists of convolutional layers, max-pooling layers, a flattening layer, and densely connected layers. The input shape is set to (28, 28, 3) to accommodate color images. The final dense layer outputs 100 classes, which aligns with the CIFAR-100 dataset.
def create_global_model():
   global_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
       tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 3)),
       tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
       tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
       tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
       tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
       tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)  # Update to 100 for CIFAR-100
    ])
    return global_model

Before implementing the compute_local_gradient() method, my objective was to compute the gradients of the global model based on a set of features and labels provided. This method calculates the categorical cross-entropy loss between predicted logits and actual labels. Additionally, it computes gradients with respect to the model's trainable variables, applies gradient clipping to control their norms, updates accuracy metrics, and logs the metrics for monitoring.
def compute_local_gradient(global_model, global_weights, features, labels, clip_norm=1.0):
    global_model.set_weights(global_weights)
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        features = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 28, 28, 3])  # Reshape to original shape
        logits = global_model(features)
        
        # Ensure labels are of the correct data type
        labels = tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.float32)
        
        # Calculate the Mean Squared Error (MSE) loss
        # loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(labels - q_values))
        
        # Calculate the categorical cross-entropy loss using CategoricalCrossentropy
        loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        loss = loss_fn(labels, logits)
    
    # Compute and return gradients
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, global_model.trainable_variables)
    
    # Apply gradient clipping to control the norm of gradients
    gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, clip_norm)
    
    accuracy_fn = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    accuracy_fn.update_state(labels, tf.nn.softmax(logits))
    accuracy = accuracy_fn.result()
    
    # Log metrics to TensorBoard
    log_metrics(round_num, loss.numpy(), accuracy.numpy())
    
    return gradients

Before compiling the global model, I intended to configure its training process. The optimizer is set to Adam, and the loss function is categorical cross-entropy. Furthermore, accuracy is monitored during training.
global_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                     loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                     metrics=['accuracy'])

Before processing the testing dataset, my aim was to prepare the features and labels for evaluation. Features and labels from different clients are gathered, preprocessed, and batched. Then, they are concatenated to form the complete testing dataset.
test_features = []
test_labels = []

for client_id in cifar_test.client_ids:
    client_data = cifar_test.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client_id)
    client_data = client_data.map(preprocess).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    for features, labels in client_data:
        test_features.append(features)
        test_labels.append(labels)

        # Convert one-hot encoded labels to class labels
        true_labels = np.concatenate([np.argmax(labels.numpy(), axis=1)])

# Concatenate the features and labels
test_features = tf.concat(test_features, axis=0)
test_labels = tf.concat(test_labels, axis=0)

test_features = tf.transpose(test_features, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])

# Compute predictions for the test dataset
predictions = global_model.predict(test_features)


# Evaluate the global model using the test dataset
test_loss, test_accuracy = global_model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels, verbose=0)

# Convert one-hot encoded labels to class labels
#true_labels = np.concatenate([y.numpy() for x, y in cifar_test])

# Convert softmax probabilities to class predictions
predicted_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

predicted_labels = tf.one_hot(predicted_labels, depth=100)  # Convert predicted labels to one-hot encoded format

# Convert test_labels and predicted_labels to numpy arrays
test_labels_np = test_labels.numpy()
predicted_labels_np = predicted_labels.numpy()

# Compute precision, recall, and F1 score
precision = precision_score(test_labels, predicted_labels, average='weighted')
recall = recall_score(test_labels, predicted_labels, average='weighted')
f1 = f1_score(test_labels, predicted_labels, average='weighted')


The predictions variable holds the model's predictions for the testing dataset. Subsequently, the global model is evaluated on the testing dataset to compute test loss and accuracy.
Finally, after obtaining predictions and true labels, I aimed to compute additional evaluation metrics such as precision, recall, and F1 score using scikit-learn's functions.
What I Tried:
Trained a deep learning model on a Cifar-100 dataset.
During training, the model achieved nearly zero loss and approximately 70% accuracy.
Evaluated the same model on a testing dataset.
Here is the testing results after the complete training the model
Test Loss: 0.23257446289062
Test Accuracy: 0.012199999764561653
Precision: 0.0009608148687758147
Recall: 0.0122
F1 Score: 0.0011736811824734595

Hi, I have reviewed your code and suggest to increasing the model complexity
by adding more kernels and layers, and use techniques like dropout and
batch_normalization.Finally, perform hyperparameter tuning using Keras Tuner
to optimize the model. These changes will enhance the model performance
